# Will python class __init__ method implicitly return None?

Tags: python

I tried to return a value in a class constructor (**init**):

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    return 1
```

but there is a run-time error saying **init** should return None. If this is the case, how to understand:

```
a=A()
```

where "a" is assigned as the class instance?

Comment: `__new__()` makes it an instance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's not `A.__new__()` that's creating the the instance `a`.

When you define `class A(object):` (or `class A:` as well if you are using Python3, `class A:` is the [*old-style* class that has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)), it is `__new__` from the inherited`object.__new__()` that is being called to create the instance `a`.

When `a = A()` is executed, what happens is:

1. `A()` is a shorthand for `A.__call__`
2. `object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` where `cls=A`, is what actually happens under hood to create instance `a`. It allocates the memory for the new object, and *should* then return a new object (the instance).
3. *if and only if* the newly created object is returned does `__init__(self)` *then* get called with the newly created object passed to it to "initilize" the object.

Consider the following demo:

- when we override `__new__` and no longer returns an object, `__init__` will
  not get called:

  ```
  class A(object):

      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          print cls, args, kwargs

      def __init__(self):
          self.x = 'init!'
          print self.x


  In : a = A()
  <class '__main__.A'> () {}

  # note that "init!" has not appeared here because __new__ didn't return an
  # new instance
  ```
- now, return a new instance by using `object.__new__`, and you will see that
  after `__new__`, `__init__` would be called as well:

  ```
  class A(object):

      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          print cls, args, kwargs
          return object.__new__(cls, args, kwargs)

      def __init__(self):
          self.x = 'init!'
          print self.x

  In : a = A()
  <class '__main__.A'> () {}
  init!
  ```

---

Here is another demo to display the difference, note that instance `a` can be created without calling `__init__()`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "init!"
        print self.x

In : a = object.__new__(A)

In : a
Out: <__main__.A at 0x103466450>

In : a.__dict__
Out: {}


In : aa = A()
init!

In : aa
Out: <__main__.A at 0x1033ddf50>

In : aa.__dict__
Out: {'x': 'init!'}
```

---

### Now for the inquisitive (and also to refresh my own memory =]):

Roughly speaking, there are two main ways to create new objects in Python:

#### Create new object (*type* / *class*) by subclassing:

`class` statements tells Python to create a new *type* / *class* object(by
subclassing an existing *type*/*class* such as `object`):

```
class Hello(object):
    pass
>>> Hello.__class__
<type 'type'>
```

In fact all *class*/*type* object have type `type`. The type of `type`
(`type(type)`) is still type.

You can subclass a *type* / *class* object.

#### Create new object (*instance*) by instantiating:

You can also create a new object by instatiating an existing *type* object.
This is done via the using the `__call__` operator (shorthand by `()`):

```
>>> h = hello()
>>> type(h)
<class '__main__.Hello'>
>>> type(int('1'))
<type 'int'>
```

**You cannot subclass an instance object.**

(note that you can also create a new *instance* object by some other means such
as using the list operator `[1,2,3]`, in this case it creates an list instance)

You can check an object's type by `type(my_obj)` or `my_object.__class__`.

---

### Now you know how an instance object is created, but what *really* creates the *type* / *class* object (that allows to create instance objects)?

In fact, these objects are created by instantiation as well, albeit it is a
slightly different kind of instantiation from what was mentioned earlier.

Aside from `class` statement, you can also use 
`type(cls_name, parent_class_tuple, attr_dict)` to create a new class.
For eg:

```
type('Hello', (object,), {})
```

will create the `Hello` class same as the one shown earlier.

What is `type`? Enter *metaclass*.

`type` is a *metaclass*, which is the class of *class*, i.e., classes are 
instances of metaclasses. The `__class__` of `type` is still `type`.

So here is a graph that shows the relationships between *metaclass*, *class*,
*instance*:

```
            instantiate             instantiate
metaclass   --------------> class   ---------------->    instance
            type.__new__()          object.__new__()
```

When metaclass `type` is called to create a new class, the similar flow goes:

1. `type.__call__()` is excuted
2. `type.__new__()` allocates memory and then returns new a class (a metaclass instace), and then calls `type.__init__()`.
3. `type.__init__()` initalizes the newly created class that was passed from step 2.

You can even create a new metaclass by subclassing `type`:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        # do something
        return super(MyMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # do something
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

then you can create a new class from this `MyMeta` metaclass just like you do
with `type`:

```
MyClass = MyMeta('MyClass', (object, ), {'x': 1})
```

Or, use `__metaclass__` when defining your class, which has exactly the
same effect as what was shown above:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
    x = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

It works like this:

You do:

```
a = A()
```

`A.__new__()` is called, and returns an instance of the class `A`.

Equivalently:

```
a = A.__new__(A)
```

Python then calls

```
a.__init__()
```

Which, as the error message says, should not return a value.

Comment: I think it calls `object.__new__(A)` or `A.__new__(A)` with `A` as an argument, because `A.__new__()` without arguments raises *TypeError* saying *object.__new__(): not enough arguments*

Comment: @hus787: Yes you're right. I was simplifying things a bit. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

As you know, everything in Python is an object, and classes are not an exception. Class `A` is an object with a method `__call__(...)` which is what allows you to write things like `a = A()`. Under the hood, `A.__call__` will first create an object using a static method `__new__` (which has a reasonable default implementation) and then calls the new object's `__init__` with the proper constructor args.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement that `__init__` should return `None` is a concious implementation choice, that lets you rely on the fact that object of type class consistantly returns an object 
of type instance of class. It's the same in many other languages such as C++.

If implemented differently it would create useless confusion.