# TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'dict'

Tags: python

Working on a Code Kata, I've got this code:

```
class Dictionary():
    def __init__(self):
        return {}                  # my code
        
    def newentry(self, word, definition):
        self[word] = definition    # my code
        return self                # my code
```

and the test I have is:

```
d = Dictionary()   
d.newentry("Apple", "A fruit")
```

which fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    d = Dictionary()
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'dict'
```

Any suggestions why a Dictionary class should return None rather than a `dict`?

Comment: ``__init__`` is an initialiser, not a constructor. It should *initialise* ``self`` and be done with it. *``__init__`` should never return anything*, because there is nothing that would use the return value. What do you assume happens with ``self`` in your code? What do you assume is the type of the ``{}`` in your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will python class ``__init__`` method implicitly return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043359/will-python-class-init-method-implicitly-return-none)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491819/how-to-return-a-value-from-init-in-python

Comment: "Any suggestions why a Dictionary class should return None rather than a dict?" Well, what is your reasoning why it should return a dict rather than None? In your own words, what do you think is the purpose of `__init__`, and how are you expecting it to work? Have you created classes in Python before? If not, do you have examples to work from? At your level of experience I think we can expect a certain level of problem-solving skills, even in a new programming language.

Comment: @Demi-Lune I don't think that's a good enough match to close as a duplicate. The other person wanted to return a value in order to indicate success or failure of initialization; this one wants to return a `dict` in order to have the resulting object behave like a `dict`, or at least to gain access to the `dict.__setitem__` machinery.

Comment: Anyway: "Working on a Code Kata, I've got this code:" It would help if we could see the actual kata in question.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to have an object variable. As pointed out in comments, `__init__` is an initialiser not a constructor

```
In [7]: class Dictionary():
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.d = {}                 # my code
   ...:
   ...:     def newentry(self, word, definition):
   ...:         self.d[word] = definition    # my code
   ...:         return self
   ...:
   ...:

In [8]: d = Dictionary()
   ...: d.newentry("Apple", "A fruit")
Out[8]: <__main__.Dictionary at 0x11f44b748>
```

Comment: That said, in languages like C++ where it's normal to write actual constructors, one *still* doesn't `return` a value from them.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's the same in java too